# "Electrwd" group?

Tags: computational-chemistry

The [Amber](http://ambermd.org/) force field parameters describe hydrogen atoms in various states:

```
HC 1.008                             H aliph. bond. to C without electrwd.group
H1 1.008                             H aliph. bond. to C with 1 electrwd. group
H2 1.008                             H aliph. bond. to C with 2 electrwd.groups
H3 1.008                             H aliph. bond. to C with 3 eletrwd.groups
HA 1.008                             H arom. bond. to C without elctrwd. groups
H4 1.008                             H arom. bond. to C with 1 electrwd. group
H5 1.008                             H arom. bond. to C with 2 electrwd. groups
```

But I cannot figure what they mean by 'electrwd group' and it doesn't specify anywhere in the documentation. I'm hoping it will be glaringly obvious to a chemist...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

electron-withdrawing (e.g. F in CF3COOH)